# Notify Swing Worker thread

Tags: java, swing, swingworker

I am using Swing Worker to show progress dialog and run the background process. I need functionality like when user clicks on cancel button of progress dialog the confirmation dialog is displayed , the process will wait for user input and if user selects yes the process stops. If user selects no the process will continue.
I am able to stop the background process using SwingWorker.cancel function but not able to start the process again if user clicks on no button.

Comment: for better help sooner post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), short, runnable, compilable, just about a.m. issue

Answer (score 1):

`SwingWorker` cannot be restarted once cancelled. Similar to basic `Threads`, they execute once. From the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html)

> SwingWorker is only designed to be executed once.

You could simply have each button dismiss the cancel dialog with the "No" button taking no additional action on the `SwingWorker`.